# Python algorithms/models specifically crashing computer

Tags: python, ubuntu, crash

I'm encountering a reoccurring issue where running any in-depth scikit/ML/clustering/etc python model will immediately crash my computer. Specifically all data manipulation and normal python programs run fine, but as soon as I send a modeling command it's an instant crash. I'm running on Ubuntu 20.04 but the problem also persisted in Ubuntu 18, I've been through multiple full OS installs and tried via CLI/jupyter notebook/pip/conda package installs. The scripts run fine on my other workstation.

I bought the computer used and it game with a high cpu/memory OC, but I've also tested at stock settings and still encountered the crash. I'm wondering if the previous user turned off some AVX instructions that these model/cluster algorithms tend to implement. It's a i-9900x, tachi x299, 64gb 4100mhz.

Comment: Are you asking if someone can tell what the previous user of a machine they have no access to did prior to your ownership of it?

Comment: No I'm asking if people have knowledge or experience with settings that could cause python algos specifically to crash, whether that's a bios or OS setting.